# How to rip DVD's in high quality

Tags: dvd

I am currently backing up (ripping) my dvd collection onto my server harddrive, to allow streaming throughout my house. I am using Acidrip to do the ripping. My problem is that the quality video of the rip is not as good as I would like, and the file size is a little too big. I downloaded an .avi rip of the blu-ray movie "black hawk down" the other day, and the quality was very good. I believe it was a 720p rip. But the file size was only 700mb. When I rip regular dvd's I choose a high bitrate (around.22) but my file sizes are anywhere from 1000mb to 1200mb, and the quality is nowhere near as good. How can i use acid rip to rip a high quality video at a 700mb file size? Is there better software, or is there something I'm missing in Acidrip?

Comment: Are you asking how to use AcidRip or a different recommendation for additional software?

Comment: Give HandBreak a try, which is a cross-platform DVD ripper, that gets the job done in decent quality. Another advantage is the wide variety of functionality and MKV + MP4 support.             https://launchpad.net/~handbrake-ubuntu/+archive/ppa

Comment: For anyone else looking for this, this is the new handbrake https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases

Comment: Just to make sure everyone knows, the old ppa has only old versions of Handbrake. Use the repository @DoDoGo published. Just installed Handbrake on Ubuntu 13.04 and it works like a charm.

Comment: There is [k9copy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k9copy/) as well, as explained [here](http://linuxowns.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/how-to-rip-a-dvd-in-ubuntu-to-avi-the-easy-way/). Seems to only be supported up to 12.10.

Answer (score 19):

Check out [this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/best-linux-dvd-ripper.html).  It's a poll of various different Linux DVD rippers - the most popular being Handbrake, followed by dvd::rip, and then some others.

Comment: I found OGMRip to be extremely user friendly. It's not the fastest, but the results are just as good - and ease of use is important to me, so it's a winner.

Answer (score 4):

I used [acidrip](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/acidrip/). I find it much simpler then dvd::rip or handbrake.

Answer (score 3):

I've found handbrake to be a lot easier to use, and it has more/better presets that you can use.  You can try using its "target size" setting to control the output size but potentially lose some quality.  It's very likely that the existing rip you found had done this, and your version should be higher quality.

https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/AvgBitrateAndTargetSize

Comment: I had problems getting `dvdrip` to do any ripping. `acidrip` ripped but the quality was terrible, no doubt because i used default settings since i don't know what half the settings are about. `handbrake` wouldn't install initially because it's repository has no directory for saucy, but following the instructions here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/install-handbrake-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/ got me going and it worked great first time.

Answer (score 3):

[DVD::RIP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/dvdrip/) is great - you can select a DVD image directory, and it copies into your harddisk before ripping. I think it's useful when you get DVD and want to rip it.

Comment: can I use this on server or do i need a GUI?