# Saving DVDs losslessly

Tags: video, dvd, cd, video-conversion

I have a bunch of DVDs/CDs that are slowly collecting dust because I almost never pull out the DVDs. There's an assortment of home videos, songs/movies/photos I've burnt on myself, songs/movies/photos that another service (ex. Costco) has burnt on for me, and commercial songs/videos.

I would like to be able to pull these from the DVDs losslessly, so that I can put it on my NAS and play it as I wish. I don't really care about the codec and whatnot as long as it's lossless (beyond what's already lost). I can pull the `.vob` files as reccomended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/235938/1091522), but I have files with the extensions `.bup`, `.ifo`, and `.vob`. What do the other extensions do and are they needed?

I don't *really* care about ripping the commercial movies/songs as I can always rebuy them. How would I losslessly pull the files from the DVDs/CDs to my hard drive?

Comment: Don't think lossless is possible, other then that ... [How to rip DVD's in high quality](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111678/how-to-rip-dvds-in-high-quality)

Comment: @mikewhatever - the other post suggests copying over the `.vob` files as lossless. I'm just wondering if the other files help and if there's any way to neatly package them. If not, I plan to use the highest setting on handbrake

Comment: Re-encoding can be lossless or not. It makes little sense to talk about a lossless copy of a file, if in isn't the same, it's not a copy. You may want to look it up about the other files.

Comment: To save audio files in a lossless *format*, try .flac . An extraordinarily convenient tool that I used for ripping my collection to .flac years ago is `abcde`, which is still in the Ubuntu repositories and great as ever. flac files tend to be large, I export to other (lossy-but-small) formats for memory-constrained devices.

Comment: Look into MakeMKV as a `.mkv` file is uncompressed so it would be lossless but everything of your choosing from the disc is in the nice and neat `.mkv` file.